# clear newlines in several texts with list comprehension doesn't work

Tags: python

i'd like to replace newlines ('\r\n') with whitespace(' ') in several texts using list comprehension.
I tried the following:

```
url1 = 'https://www.gutenberg.org/files/345/345.txt'
dracula = urllib2.urlopen(url1).read()

url2 = 'https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/18223/pg18223.txt'
buddhism = urllib2.urlopen(url2).read()

url3 = 'https://www.gutenberg.org/files/14776/14776.txt'
horses = urllib2.urlopen(url3).read()

texte = [dracula, buddhism, horses]
texte = [text.replace('\r\n', ' ') for text in texte]
```

--> doesn't work - newlines ('\r\n') are still there!

BUT the same kind of code with a more simple list of texts worked:

```
text1 = "23482304 \r\nd34\r\n\r\n"
text2 = "\r\nas doi\r\nuas \r\n ou"
text3 = "trolo\r\nlol"

liste = [text1, text2, text3]

liste = [i.replace("\r\n", " ") for i in liste]
```

--> all newlines were replaced!

- Does anybody have an idea what went wrong?

Comment: How it doesn't work? the newlines are still where? did you for example printed `horses` ?

Comment: yes I printed a random sequence 
`horses[70000:71000]`
-> output: "ady, determined purpose while you are whipping him. There is\r\nhardly one balking horse in five hundred that will pull true from\r\nwhipping; it is only adding fuel to fire, and will make them more liab...

Answer (score 1):

The `str.replace` method returns a new object and you need to re assign it to main object if you want to change it :

```
>>> text1 = "23482304 \r\nd34\r\n\r\n"
>>> text2 = "\r\nas doi\r\nuas \r\n ou"
>>> text3 = "trolo\r\nlol"
>>> 
>>> liste = [text1, text2, text3]
>>> 
>>> liste = [i.replace("\r\n", " ") for i in liste]
>>> liste
['23482304  d34  ', ' as doi uas   ou', 'trolo lol']
>>> text1
'23482304 \r\nd34\r\n\r\n'
```

Also since strings are immutable you can not modify them using a list comprehension or changing a copy of them You need to change them directly :

for example :

```
>>> text1 = "23482304 \r\nd34\r\n\r\n"
>>> text1=text1.replace("\r\n", " ")
>>> text1
'23482304  d34  '
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use readlines() and go through each item in the list and remove the `\r\n` on those lines, then join the items in the list together

```
import urllib2
url1 = 'https://www.gutenberg.org/files/345/345.txt'
dracula = urllib2.urlopen(url1).readlines()

url2 = 'https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/18223/pg18223.txt'
buddhism = urllib2.urlopen(url2).readlines()

url3 = 'https://www.gutenberg.org/files/14776/14776.txt'
horses = urllib2.urlopen(url3).readlines()

texte = [dracula, buddhism, horses]
texte = [line.replace('\r\n', '') for text in texte for line in text]

print ''.join(texte)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not modifying the original strings `dracula`, `buddhism`, and `horses` by this code (I'm not sure if that's what you intended).

`replace()` returns a new copy of the string. You are creating new copies of each with the `\r\n` characters removed and rebinding these new copies created in the list comprehension to `texte`.

```
texte = [dracula, buddhism, horses]
texte = [text.replace('\r\n', ' ') for text in texte]

>>> for s in dracula, buddhism, horses:
...     print '\r\n' in s
True
True
True

>>> for s in texte:
...     print '\r\n' in s
False
False
False
```

This behaviour is identical to your second example:

```
text1 = "23482304 \r\nd34\r\n\r\n"
text2 = "\r\nas doi\r\nuas \r\n ou"
text3 = "trolo\r\nlol"

liste = [text1, text2, text3]
liste = [i.replace("\r\n", " ") for i in liste]

>>> for s in text1, text2, text3:
...     print '\r\n' in s
True
True
True

>>> for s in liste:
...     print '\r\n' in s
False
False
False
```

You could do it by rebinding the original variables to the filtered copies like this:

```
>>> dracula, buddhism, horses = [text.replace('\r\n', ' ') for text in texte]
>>> for s in dracula, buddhism, horses:
...     print '\r\n' in s
False
False
False
```

Comment: great, thats what I wanted to do - thanks!
I thought this code `texte = [text.replace('\r\n', ' ') for text in texte]` would do the same as `dracula, buddhism, horses = [text.replace('\r\n', ' ') for text in texte]` didn't know I can write 'dracula, buddhism, horses =...'